# How to do the CURD operation in IBM Object Storage in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I am trying to implement the IBM cloud object storage using ATS API in NodeJS.

Is there any examples related to CRUD operation in the cloud API object to retrieve using NodeJS?

Comment: `I am trying to implement`, what did you tried?? Please post the code of your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try this NPM package this does the job pretty neatly 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk.
Here is sample code from the npm package docs:

```
    var AWS = require('ibm-cos-sdk');
    var util = require('util');

    var config = {
        endpoint: '<endpoint>',
        apiKeyId: '<api-key>',
        serviceInstanceId: '<resource-instance-id>',
    };

    var cos = new AWS.S3(config);

    function doCreateBucket() {
        console.log('Creating bucket');
        return cos.createBucket({
            Bucket: 'my-bucket',
            CreateBucketConfiguration: {
              LocationConstraint: 'us-standard'
            },
        }).promise();
    }

    function doCreateObject() {
        console.log('Creating object');
        return cos.putObject({
            Bucket: 'my-bucket',
            Key: 'foo',
            Body: 'bar'
        }).promise();
    }

    function doDeleteObject() {
        console.log('Deleting object');
        return cos.deleteObject({
            Bucket: 'my-bucket',
            Key: 'foo'
        }).promise();
    }

    function doDeleteBucket() {
        console.log('Deleting bucket');
        return cos.deleteBucket({
            Bucket: 'my-bucket'
        }).promise();
    }

    doCreateBucket()
        .then(doCreateObject)
        .then(doDeleteObject)
        .then(doDeleteBucket)
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Finished!');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('An error occurred:');
            console.error(util.inspect(err));
        });
```

Comment: How to do the rename operation. I have tried to copy the files it's not working                           ` cos.copyObject({
            Bucket: 'file-ej22',
            Key: 'Files/',
            CopySource: 'file-ej22/Files/'
        }).promise().then(function (data) {
     
        })` eGetting error related to invalid copy source

Comment: This is a new question all together and need more details like error log/stack trace. Before posting the question do try to google it and read the stackoverflow guidelines for posting a question.

Comment: Error` NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.`